# How to make an embed with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

I was wondering how to write an embed in `discord.js`. This is my current code: it is not functional. I get the warning: 'message is not defined' on `message.channel.send` I do not know how to fix this. I was hoping you guys could tell me how to fix this.
js

```
message.channel.send(generateEmbed(0)).then((message) => {
  if (guilds.length <= 10) return;

  message.react(":right_arrow:");
  const collector = message.createReactionCollector(
    (reaction, user) =>
      [":left_arrow:", ":right_arrow"].includes(reaction.emoji.name) &&
      user.id === message.author.id,
    // time out after a minute
    { time: 60000 }
  );

  let currentIndex = 0;
  collector.on("collect", (reaction) => {
    message.reactions.removeAll().then(async () => {
      reaction.emoji.name === ":left_emoji:"
        ? (currentIndex -= 10)
        : (currentIndex += 10);

      message.edit(generateEmbed(currentIndex));

      if (currentIndex !== 0) await message.react(":left_arrow:");
      // react with right arrow if it isn't the end
      if (currentIndex + 10 < guilds.length) message.react(":right_arrow:");
    });
  });
});

bot.login(token);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you *did* define `message`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the message object you have to listen to the event "on" with parameters "message" and the function that executes the code that needs the message object:

```
bot.on("message", function(message) {
    //your code that uses message
});
```

For the embed you can directly go to the official discord.js documentation at: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed, where it is fully explained.

Answer (score 1):

Extremely easy to do actually.
This is a good template for an embed:

```
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor('Some name', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png', 'https://discord.js.org')
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addField('Inline field title', 'Some value here', true)
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Some footer text here', 'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png');

// Code to send embed
channel.send(exampleEmbed);
```